# Shipping personal effects from USA to Italy

Tags: usa, italy, shipping, relocation

I am soon relocating from USA (New York, NY) to Italy. I have a bunch of personal effects (e.g., clothes, books, a game console, some souvenirs) that I would like to ship to Italy. I think I can fit these into two large boxes, say max 60-65 lbs (30 kg) each (probably less).

Any suggestion on how to do that in a relatively cheap (and secure) way?
I have been looking at prices on UPS, FedEx, and DHL, and they are astronomical. Time is not a primary concern, it may take up to a couple of weeks (as long as it is secure).

Also, how to avoid VAT or customs? All of these are personal belongings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my limited personal experience I suggest pack them into the extra hold baggage of your flight to Italy. Otherwise, the least I've paid was 200 pounds sterling for half a pallet from UK to Italy, most was over 5000 for half a shipping container also UK to Italy (included paying company for packing and 6 months storage.
Website https://www.bonvu.com/shippingcalculator/shippingCalculator.php quotes prices from around $ 250 upwards - provide better dimensions and get better results.

I suppose I should edit this to address the customs and tax: you don't avoid them, but declare them on the required form as personal effects, if necessary include evidence of age and value (receipts). Again, only have experience relocating five times beteeen European states and sometimes I used a firm other times I did the form myself: doing it myself was far easier and cheaper.